# Why am I unable to print the proper output produced using the kable function from the knitr package?

Tags: r, knitr, kableextra

I have been trying to print a data dictionary using the kable function. Here is my code:

```
dict<-build_dict(my.data = tweets_train,linker=linker,option_description = NULL, prompt_varopts = T)
kable(dict,format="latex",caption="Data dictionary for the Training dataset") %>%
  kable_styling(position = "center")
```

And this is the output:

```
> kable(dict,format="latex",caption="Data dictionary for the Training dataset") %>%
+   kable_styling(position = "center")

\begin{table}

\caption{\label{tab:}Data dictionary for the Training dataset}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{l|l|l|l}
\hline
variable name & variable description & variable options & notes\\
\hline
sentiment & Sentiment Score 0 for Negative sentences and 4 for Positive sentences & 0 to 4 & The polarity of the tweet (0 = negative, 2 = neutral, 4 = positive)\\
\hline
text & The tweets collected & ''  oh u can take me to the game with u  mor  to zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz so tired   good night hokies & The dataset Sentiment 140 that originated from Stanford University for the purpose of Training\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

How do I rectify this. Using knitr for the first time as I had to create a data dictionary. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem with the output? If you include that code in an RMarkdown file (outputting to PDF) it should be OK, is that what you're doing?

Comment: Probably yeah! Tried using knitr for the first time. Sorry but just one more question: do I include kable(dict,format="latex",caption="Data dictionary for the Training dataset") %>%
  kable_styling(position = "center") in a markdown file is it?

Comment: You would most likely have to shift *all* your code from the current R script over to the RMarkdown file (easy to create in RStudio if you're using that). The alternative would be to copy the latex code that is produced (what you're seeing in your current output) into a LaTeX file, but it seems like you're not familiar with LaTeX so RMarkdown may be the easier option.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to shift your code as mentionned by @Marius

You need to put it in a markdown file as below:

[image: Open markdown file]

paste this in the r chunk

```
dict<-build_dict(my.data = tweets_train,linker=linker,
                 option_description = NULL, prompt_varopts = T)
knitr::kable(dict,format="latex",caption="Data dictionary for the Training dataset") %>%
knitr::kable_styling(position = "center")
```

like that and put knitr before kable to call the library itself (or call it before `library(knitr)`) :

[image]

Then save and knit :)
Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for that! Appreciate it.